# XmlHttpRequest.onload not working in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, onload

I'm running into an issue where Microsoft Edge browser isn't able to execute `XmlHttpRequest.onload`. But it does execute in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

I'm creating an XmlHttpRequest object:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "json";
xhr.open("POST", authenticateUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-OpenAM-Username", email);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-OpenAM-Password", password);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

alert("XHR object is created"); 

xhr.onload = function () {
  alert("start onload...");

  //...receives response from service...
}

xhr.send();
```

The alerts in place to validate it's reaching a specific line of code. After the XMLHttpRequest object is created, the code goes into the `onload` function. Microsoft Edge won't go into it. As I said, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari execute this code fine.

Is there something additional needed for making Microsoft Edge run this code?

Comment: What are you expecting? I tried your snippet on all major browsers and none of them fire `onload` until the request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

The onload function shouldn't be called until you send the XHR and the response comes back (unless there is an error). Are you calling xhr.send()?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload

Comment: The example on the MDN page you linked also does `send()` only after defining `.onload`.

Comment: Yes, `xhr.send();` is getting called after the `onload` returns a response from the XHR.

Comment: Interesting. Does onreadystatechange work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Comment: I try to make a test with your code but onload event not get execute in any browser. Can you show your testing results. so that we can check it.

Comment: Can you use that instead of onload? Not sure why onload isn't work but maybe you can get around it.

Comment: @DaveB that's an interesting idea. I might be able to, but I wonder if I *need* to be using `onload` properly (downstream issues?).

Answer (score 0):

Place the `xhr.responseType = "json"` line after the `xhr.open(...)`

Because the `xhr.responseType` is not allowed for synchronous requests which is determined by the third parameter in the `open()` call.

Wait, that was in IE11, i've tried your snippet in Edge and it ran just fine.

Try adding a

```
xhr.onerror = err => alert('Error:' + err.message);
```

to see if an error occurred.

Comment: I moved the responseType after `xhr.open()` but that didn't resolve it.